# this BASH code works on a command line, but not when i move it into a script

Tags: bash, debugging, shell

I built-up a kludgey script on the CLI that I can't successfully move into a text file. **I know it's poorly-written, but I'm interested in resolving the problem I'm having, not re-writing it.** I want to understand why my poorly-written code behaves differently when executed on the command line compared to when it's saved as a file.

I think it's related to something getting interpolated prematurely in the script, because if I substitute the one-liner version into the same file (without formatting) I get identical output. Note the debug line below and how it doesn't print.

**CONTENTS OF SCRIPT**

```
#!/bin/bash

totalNodes=0             #initialize sum                                                                                     
echo -e "ID\t\t\tNODES"; #title line                                                                                         
for n2 in $(             #n2 will get populated with the number of nodes (to be added to totalNodes)                         
    for n in $(          #n is an intermediate string that munges the Resource_list.nodes line (kludgy)                      
        for i in $(
            qstat|grep " ef "|cut -f 1 -d ' ')     #i gets the ef queue lines                                                
        do
            echo "debug $i"
            j=$(echo $i|sed 's/(\d+)\..+/\$1/');    #j is the actual ID                                                      
            qstat -f | grep -A43 $j;               #extracts the full output from qstat for this job ID                      
        done|grep Resource_List.nodes)             #closes definition of n over loop                                         
    do echo ${n};done|grep ppn)                    #closes definition of n2 over loop                                        
do
   echo "$j ${n2:0:1}"                             #output line                                                              
   totalNodes=$(($totalNodes+${n2:0:1}))           #counting nodes                                                           
done
echo "$totalNodes nodes of 16 running in EF queue"
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT** (what I get at the command line):

```
ID          NODES
2378512.yaddayadday-adm 4
2378512.yaddayadday-adm 4
2378512.yaddayadday-adm 4
2378512.yaddayadday-adm 2
14 nodes of 16 running in EF queue
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT** from the script

```
ID          NODES
 4
 4
 4
 2
14 nodes of 16 running in EF queue
```

So I'm confused how I can get the right total (meaning $n2 is getting defined correctly) but I can't even print $i on the debug-with-print line (line 8.)

For reference, here's the one-liner. Like I said, **this gives the "EXPECTED OUTPUT" shown above, when executed on the command line, but the same output as the above codeblock "CONTENTS OF SCRIPT" when I save it as a file with no additional formatting.**

```
totalNodes=0;echo -e "ID\t\t\tNODES";for n2 in $(for n in $(for i in $(qstat|grep " ef "|cut -f 1 -d ' ');do j=$(echo $i|sed 's/(\d+)\..+/$1/');qstat -f | grep -A43 $j;done|grep Resource_List.nodes);do echo ${n};done|grep ppn);do echo "$j ${n2:0:1}";totalNodes=$(($totalNodes+${n2:0:1})); done;echo "$totalNodes nodes of 16 running in EF queue"
```

Comment: I would start by replacing `for n{2} in $(...` with a `|while read LINE; do case "$LINE in"` ... you can do the same with the output of qstat and operate on streams instead of ballooning the memory with unneeded large variables that is nearly as painful to read as recursion but with no benefit ... the read command can replace cut as well by using `read dummy0 dummy1 needed_var dummy2;`

Comment: Your variable `j` is used iteratively internally before the outer loop parses n2. How would it fit to be placed in `echo "$j ${n2:0:1}"`?

Comment: To answer your question: it's caused by subshells, as detailed in konsolebox his answer. bash is not well suited for stuff like this - a scripting language like python would be a better fit.
To address your problem, a quick and dirty option to pass data back from a child to parent is to write the output to a file. e.g `echo "debug $i" >> tmp.out` or `"your_oneliner" > tmp.out; cat tmp.out` This can also be used for intermediate results, to iterate over with `read while.`

Comment: This does not answer my question. My question is, in terms of subshells, _why do the subshells cause problems only when the script is called from a file?_

Comment: Perhaps `j` is already set to `2378512.yaddayadday-adm` in your shell before you execute the one-liner?  Do an `echo $j` to find out.  You could add some sample input to your question.

Comment: Oh excellent. I didn't notice that the value of `j` was not getting updated. You're correct about that -- because I built this up over multiple executions, I was carrying over `j` but only cosmetically. You can see in my example output that it's constant but it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command substitution method `$()` runs commands in it on a subshell so if you define a variable inside it the value of that variable would be lost outside.

```
j=1
: "$(j=2)"
echo "$j" # => 1
```

Comment: This seems like a good clue but I think I don't understand the full significance of 'subshell.' If I insert an "echo $variable-in-scope" within a $(yadda), it gives output on the command line but not in the script. Why does the subshell's behavior (or scoping) seem different in the two cases?

Comment: @Ryan Subshells simply run as a different process. If you do `echo "$(pstree)"` you'd notice that pstree is running under another instance of bash. Processes normally can't share their own variables along each other.

Comment: The recommended solution actually would be to store your output to an array for every step but perhaps a pseudocode would be helpful for that since I don't exactly know what your code wants i.e. I can't even follow why you access `$j` on the outside. Even if it's not processed inside a subshell it would still be odd since `$j` is an iterating variable on the inner part.

Comment: I have to emphasize; this works in the one-liner form and not when it's saved in a file and executed as a script. Are you explaining why that's happening, and I'm just not absorbing it, or are you explaining why it shouldn't work (and therefore missing my observation that it does work on the CLI)?

Comment: @Ryan I think I missed your point. The thing is you're actually reading the output of the echo message as well as part of the iteration since it's naturally under command substitution. If you like you could redirect your output to stderr instead e.g. `echo "debug $i" >&2`. Yet again it's still recommended to not recurse your commands in nested command substitutions like that. The redirection probably wouldn't be necessary if you're storing output by arrays instead, and many other unexpected troubles could be avoided as well.

Answer (score 0):

several bugs :

1-  qstat|grep " ef "|cut -f 1 -d ' '   is returning an empty list

2-  qstat -f | grep -A43 $j            is returning en empty list

before running the loop make sure #1 and #2 generates a valid list

since qstat|grep " ef "|cut -f 1 -d ' ' is constant , consider moving it outside the loops

$x1 = $(qstat|grep " ef "|cut -f 1 -d ' ')

use $x1 instead of above

Comment: I don't see how this explains why the bugs appear only when I'm calling the script from a file. Do you see how this is happening? Also, 'qstat -f | grep -A43 $j' can't be returning an empty list because $n2 is accumulating the correct total.

Comment: its possible qstat is running from a different path (or other scripts ). also some variable might be set in session and not in script. add a set-x at the beginning of script and put some echo in between forloops

Comment: I don't think you've identified any bugs. qstat|grep " ef "|cut -f 1 -d ' ' is not a constant. Also your definition of x1 is not valid Bash.